# Python MNE: how to compute continuous wavelets?

Tags: python, mne-python

The [Python MNE API](http://martinos.org/mne/stable/generated/mne.time_frequency.cwt_morlet.html#mne.time_frequency.cwt_morlet) says I should compute continuous wavelets by

```
mne.time_frequency.cwt_morlet(X, sampling_frequency, frequencies_of_interest)
```

However, when I make X equal to a raw .fif data file, it throws

```
287     # mode = "valid"
288     decim = _check_decim(decim)
--> 289     n_signals, n_times = X[:, decim].shape
290
291     # Precompute wavelets for given frequency range to save time

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, this function operates on NumPy arrays, not on instances of Raw. This means you have to get the data out of the Raw object. You can use the `get_data()` method for that:

```
mne.time_frequency.cwt_morlet(X.get_data(), X.info['sfreq'], frequencies_of_interest)
```